# Переписать правило в nginx через location

Tags: php, nginx

Переписать правило используя location

```
rewrite ^/common/imageResize.php$ /common/imageResize.php last;
if ($args ~ "w=[0-9]+"){
    set $rule_1 1;
}
if ($args ~ "h=[0-9]+"){
    set $rule_1 1;
}
if ($args ~ "^tc?$"){
    set $rule_1 1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*).(jpg|gif|png) /common/imageResize.php?name=$request_filename&$args last;
}
```

Имеется такая конфигурация:

```
server {
listen      170.1.1.1:80;
server_name ex.com ;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/ex.com.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_pass      http://170.1.1.1:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           ___/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/ex.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/ex.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   ___/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://170.1.1.1:8080;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include __/ex.com.conf*;
}
```

Comment: Ну и переписывайте, мы тут при чем?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, если поможешь буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Никак. Location не матчит параметры запроса

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, я знаю, но как использовать через location не используя аргументы